# How to remove indentations or spaces from HTML comment tags?

Tags: php, html, regex, string, preg-replace

Here is my code:

```php
$template = preg_replace("\s*/\<\!\-\-\{(.+?)\}\-\-\>/s", "{\\1}", $template);
```

And the `html` which I want to remove indentations of comment:

```html
    <!--{hello}-->
    <div class="novalue">
        <a>URL</a>
    </div>
    <!--{/hello}-->
```

I want it to be like this:

```html
{hello}
    <div class="novalue">
        <a>URL</a>
    </div>
{/hello}
```

But, the result was:

```html
{hello}
        <div class="novalue">
            <a></a>
        </div>{/hello}
```

My question is, why can't it just remove other space at the front of the **current** line ?

Comment: You only need this to be done once right? So even if it's an inefficient solution then it's ok?

Comment: @Andreas Actually I use this regex in my template engine, your answer is enough for single line, but the whole template file might not work perfect.. I have just got an idea for this, I will try it tomorrow, thanks for your answer!

Comment: I'd do it [like this](https://eval.in/1107605).

Comment: @carry0987 *your answer is enough for single line, but the whole template file might not work perfect..* please share those cases when it doesn't work and I will try to improve the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\s` includes linebreak, you want to use `\h` for horizontal spaces instead And don't escape all characters in your regex, it becomes unreadable:

```
$html = <<<EOD
    <!--{hello}-->
    <div class="novalue">
        <a>URL</a>
    </div>
    <!--{/hello}-->
EOD;

echo preg_replace('#\h*<!--({.+?})-->#', '$1', $html);
```

**Output:**

```
{hello}
    <div class="novalue">
        <a>URL</a>
    </div>
{/hello}
```

**Explanation:**

```
#           # regex delimiter
  \h*       # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  <!--      # literally, begin comment
  (         # start group 1
    {       # opening curly brace
    .+?     # 1 or more any character, not greedy
    }       # closing curly brace
  )         # end group 1
  -->       # literally, end comment
#           # regex delimiter
```

Comment: Another little question, why ` *` slower then `\h*`? They take same steps (1376 steps), but `\h*` use 2ms, and ` *` use 3ms

Comment: So... what you recommend to use ? ` *` or `\h*` ? I'm not sure which one was better for this case..

Comment: @carry0987: ` *` matches 0 or more single space, `\h*` matches 0 or more horizontal spaces (i.e. space or tabulation)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I think that if I just want to clean horizontal spaces, use `\h*` is better

Answer (score 1):

You can loop as long as you find a `space comment` and then remove it with str_replace.
When the loop is done just remove the `<!--` parts.

```
while(strpos($str, ' <!--{hello}-->') !== false){
    $str = str_replace(" <!--{hello}-->", "<!--{hello}-->",$str);
    $str = str_replace(" <!--{/hello}-->", "<!--{/hello}-->",$str);
}
$str = str_replace(["<!--{hello}-->", "<!--{/hello}-->"], ["{hello}", "{/hello}"],$str);


echo $str;
```

https://3v4l.org/9oGWu

Example input:

```
    <!--{hello}-->
    <div class="novalue">
        <a>URL</a>
    </div>
    <!--{/hello}-->

        <!--{hello}-->
        <div class="novalue">
            <a>URL</a>
        </div>
        <!--{/hello}-->

<!--{hello}-->
<div class="novalue">
    <a>URL</a>
</div>
<!--{/hello}-->
```

Returns:

```
{hello}
    <div class="novalue">
        <a>URL</a>
    </div>
{/hello}

{hello}
        <div class="novalue">
            <a>URL</a>
        </div>
{/hello}

{hello}
<div class="novalue">
    <a>URL</a>
</div>
{/hello}
```

Comment: The test result of this answer can take more than 20ms in template engine, test in PHP 7.0.1, and the regex answer take only 3ms for same result (it's really strange, str_replace should faster than regex)

Comment: @carry0987 did you take in to account the spin up and spin down of the CPU? When you make speed comparisons you should include code at the start and end that is "nonsense" like a long loop with some math or something.

Comment: Now I know it, I will test it again in whole project with both two answer

Comment: I believe you are correct that str_replace is faster, but keep in mind the regex answers does one replace, mine loops untill there is no more to do, meaning it will do as many replaces as there is indents in the most indented line of comment.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `\s*` from the start of your regex.

```regex
/\<\!\-\-\{(.+?)\}\-\-\>/s
```

then replace with

```regex
{$1}
```